# Catch inconsistent application state with Swift's `guard` statement?

Tags: swift

I've a function in Swift like so:

```
@IBAction func doSomething(_ sender: AnyObject) { }
```

I need the `sender` to be of type `NSMenuItem`, so I check it with a guard:

```
guard let menuItem = sender as? NSMenuItem else { return }
```

But this will silently let the application continue if there is some serious error in my application logic, resulting in a different object type being passed.
Wouldn't it be better to just crash the application, rather than 'presenting' the user with a mysteriously non-working function?

What is the best way to check and react for these super-basic assumptions?

Comment: Why won't you just declare `@IBAction func doSomething(_ sender: NSMenuItem)`? And you can to crash your app anytime if you want, but `guard` is designed for situations when you don not want that to happen by itself.

Comment: Do StoryBoards respect the arguments type? They do not seem to be that type-safe  to me, so I thought `@IBAction` always needed generic argument types.

Comment: Yes, they do, when you will try to link with action they will only show you action with compatible `sender`. But if you change type after linking target with action you will have a bad time though. And `@IBAction` means absolutely nothing, except that `InterfaceBuilder` should see it as possible action for target/event.

Comment: Good to hear, that solves this specific issue, but how about checking whether `NSApp.delegate` is of my custom subclass type? That also should never ever be another type unless something is very wrong.

Comment: Honestly *the best way* is to do your homework and make the code robust at **design time** rather than doing such checks at **runtime**. You – the developer – are fully responsible for *not a different object type being passed*

Comment: I see.Does that imply that I shouldn't use the `NSApp.delegate` property when I need that delegate, but acquire it via a more type-safe way?

Comment: Force downcasting is not evil per se. Using `NSApp.delegate as! AppDelegate` is perfectly fine and **safe**. This property can not be changed at runtime and the app won't even launch if the delegate class was missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you can write your `@IBAction`s like this:

```
@IBAction func doSomething(_ sender: NSMenuItem)
```

`sender` does not have to be `AnyObject`.

In other situations though, if you want to crash with a `guard` statement, you could do:

```
guard ... else { fatalError("a message") }
```

`fatalError` returns `Never`, so it can be used in the `else` clause.